# how to use flyweight pattern in composite pattern

Tags: c#, json, design-patterns, decorator, composite

I'm following O'Reilly C# Design Pattern book so I try to do some own exercise to implement some following design patterns but I can't get expect output to clear my doubt (*what are patterns should i implement to get expecting output*)

```
public interface ICook<T> //Cook Interface
{
    IIngredient Ingredient { get; }

    void Add(ICook<T> cook);
    object Display();
    ICook<T> Find(string name);
    ICook<T> Remove(ICook<T> cook);
}

public interface IIngredient //abstraction of ingredient
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Beverage: IIngredient  //same as dish ingredient
{
    private string v;

    public Beverage(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public string Name => v;
}

public class Boil<T> : Cook<T> // kind of decorator
{
    private IIngredient _ingredient;

    public Boil(IIngredient ingredient) : base(ingredient)
    {
        this._ingredient = ingredient;
        base.CookName = "Boil";
    }

    public override object Display()
    {
        return base.Display();
    }
}

public class Cook<T> : ICook<T> //single Component of Composite Pattern
{
    protected string CookName;
    private IIngredient _ingredient;
    public Cook(IIngredient ingredient)
    {
        _ingredient = ingredient;

    }

    public IIngredient Ingredient => _ingredient;
    public void Add(ICook<T> cook)
    {
        throw new Exception("Cannot Add Cook in Cook");
    }

    public virtual object Display()
    {
        return CookName;
    }

    public ICook<T> Find(string name)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



    public ICook<T> Remove(ICook<T> cook)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Dish : IIngredient // Kind of Ingredient
{
    private string v;

    public Dish(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public string Name => v;
}

public class Fry<T> : Cook<T> //same as boil class
{
    private IIngredient _ingredient;

    public Fry(IIngredient ingredient) : base(ingredient)
    {
        this._ingredient = ingredient;
        base.CookName = "Fry";
    }
    public override object Display()
    {
        return base.Display();
    }
}

public class Mix<T> : ICook<T> //collection of single components for composite pattern
{
    private IIngredient _name;
    private IList<ICook<T>> cooks;
    public Mix(IIngredient name)
    {
        _name = name;
        cooks = new List<ICook<T>>();

    }



    public IIngredient Ingredient => _name;

    public void Add(ICook<T> cook)
    {
        cooks.Add(cook);
    }

    public object Display()
    {
        return new { Ingredients = cooks.Select(c => c.Ingredient).Distinct(), cooks = cooks.Select(c => c.Display()) };
    }

    public ICook<T> Find(string name)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }



    public ICook<T> Remove(ICook<T> cook)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}



internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IIngredient raw = new Dish("Basic");
        IIngredient egg = new Dish("Chiken Egg");
        IIngredient bread = new Dish("Oat Bread");
        IIngredient milk = new Beverage("Milk");
        ICook<IIngredient> cook = new Mix<IIngredient>(raw);
        cook.Add(new Boil<IIngredient>(egg));
        cook.Add(new Fry<IIngredient>(egg));
        cook.Add(new Boil<IIngredient>(milk));
        cook.Add(new Fry<IIngredient>(bread));
        Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cook.Display()));     
    }


}
```

Actual Output is

```
{
  "Ingredients": [
    {
      "Name": "Chiken Egg"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Milk"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Oat Bread"
    }
  ],
  "cooks": [
    "Boil",
    "Fry",
    "Boil",
    "Fry"
  ]
}
```

Excepting output is

```
{
  "Ingredients": [
    {
      "Name": "Chiken Egg"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Milk"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Oat Bread"
    }
  ],
  "cooks": [
    {
      "Ingredients": [
        {
          "Name": "Chiken Egg"
        }
      ],
      "cooks": [
        "Boil",
        "Fry"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Ingredients": [
        {
          "Name": "Milk"
        }
      ],
      "cooks": [
        "Boil"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Ingredients": [
        {
          "Name": "Oat Bread"
        }
      ],
      "cooks": [
        "Fry"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and how to use flyweight pattern to minimize the same object creations to help for small applications

Comment: Just a quick note. Do you really want to add ICook when cooking something? I would expect to add IIngredient's to cook something.

Comment: @user743414 before add IIngredient to cook the ingredient should decorate or in cooked state ,any kind of techniques is related to cook is cook i.e boil,bake,fry even slicing  also kind of cooking techniques but many ingredients using same techniques to minimize duplication i decide to implement flyweight pattern in cook but no idea stucked in half